# Guard not evaluating correct file

Tags: rspec-rails, guard

I'm running Guard with rspec 3.0 and spring on Rails 4.1. When I try to write view specs for my app, guard isn't noticing the correct file being saved. For example, if I save a view spec at "/spec/views/api/v1/registrations/create.json.jbuilder_spec.rb", guard will run the spec for "/spec/controllers/api/v1/registrations_controller_spec.rb". My Guardfile is below:

```
guard :rspec, cmd: 'spring rspec', all_on_start: false do

  watch(%r{^spec/models/.+integration_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^spec/helpers/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^spec/routing/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^spec/requests/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^spec/views/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^spec/controllers/.+_spec\.rb$})

  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml|\.slim)$})          { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml|slim)$})     { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
end
```

If I comment out all of the "spec" regular expressions except for the view one, guard still has the same behaviour that I explained above. Also, this happens for every single view spec that I write. I'm not sure why this regular expression is picking this up, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It turned out that the gem guard-rspec has a default failed_mode, which is set to focus (the first 10 failed specs, no matter what you run apparently). By setting this to 'none' in my Guardfile, it fixed my problem.